# Laravel returning values of all checkboxes everytime

Tags: php, checkbox, laravel

I have a checklist in a form which gathers some information from user.I'm trying to get values of those check box which are selected by the user.

Here's the route

```
Route::get('addoption', array('as' => 'getaddoption', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@getAddOption'));
Route::post('addoption', array('as' => 'postaddoption', 'uses' => 'CategoryController@postAddOption'));
```

Here's the controller part

```
public function getCategoryForm(){

    //$this->option is a model interface which deals with table named 'options' having one column 'option'

    $existing_options = $this->option->lists('option');
    return View::make('dashboard.addcategoryform')->with('existing_options', $existing_options);
}
```

Here is the part(in dashboard.addcategory view) of form that deals with checkbox

```
@foreach($existing_options as $existing_option)
    {{Form::label($existing_option, $existing_option)}}
    {{Form::checkbox($existing_option, $existing_option)}}
@endforeach
```

So checkboxes are created. Now i want to know the values of checkbox selected by the user.

I'm processing this form via postAddOption method

```
if($validator->passes()){
    $existing_option = $this->option->lists('option');          

    foreach($existing_option as $existing_opt){
            if(Input::get($existing_opt) == true){
                $selected_option[] = $existing_opt;
        }
    }

    print_r($selected_option);
}
```

But it's giving me array of all checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

All your checkboxes should have the same name and be appended with `[]`.

```
@foreach($existing_options as $existing_option)
    {{ Form::checkbox('options[]', $existing_option) }}
@endforeach
```

Now when you submit, it will be submitted as an array which will be filled with each value of the corresponding checked checkbox's value so you will not need to loop through them.

```
if($validator->passes()){
    dd(Input::get('options'));
}
```